# Options available for reading a Dynamic Property in a Composite Application

Tags: lotus-notes

It is possible to open a Lotus Notes Composite Application (CA) using a syntax like this:
     cai:///uniqueappid/uniquepageid?hint

According to a wiki-article - 
[Passing context to components when opening composite applications](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/compappwiki.nsf/dx/passing-context-to-components-when-opening-composite-applications-) - you can pass a Dynamic property to a Composite Application and let the components in the CA read it.
The article has an example like this:

```
String[] values = data.getPreference("com.ibm.portal.app.input.NiklasTest");
```

Which should be able to read the parameter from a URL formatted like this:
    cai:///uniqueappid/uniquepageid?hint&NiklasTest=xxxxx

I am looking for what my options are in order to get a handle on such a property.

- Coding a java component. It seems likely that this would work.
- Coding an xPage component. Would it be able to get a handle on the Dynamic
  Property?
- Coding a Portlet component. Would it be able to get a
  handle on the Dynamic Property?
- Coding a NSF form- or page-based
  component. Are there LotusScript or @functions that can get a handle
  on the Dynamic Property?

I am not looking for the best soloution. I am looking for a list of options that are known to work. Basically weeding out in my list above.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of Composite Applications, and what exactly is a Dynamic Property, but in an XPage you can simply use param.NiklasTest in order to get the xxxxx from the URL.

Comment: Would using param.NiklasTest in an xPage used as a Component in a Composite Application be able to access a parameter that is in the cai-type url used for opening the Composite Application? I fear that it would not....

Answer (score 0):

In a application where we needed to pass parameters (and be able to open the CA multible times).
The (easy) solution was to build the .ca file on the fly (and embed the parameters) and then launch it.

You can build the template for the .ca file with the designer

[IBM Wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/compappwiki.nsf/dx/10282008051122PMWEBSUN.htm)

Comment: In my use case, the cai-url would get launched from a browser. I would have thousands of users doing this every hour. I see some implementation-issues ahead using your suggestion. The security-related issue - making a browser create a file locally and then activating it.